# In a house with baseboard heat, how can I tell where areas I need to heat in the winter to prevent pipe freeze?

Tags: walls, heating, pipe, baseboard, freezing

All,

I recently purchased a property in the mountains as a vacation home. It is two stories plus a basement. It has no central air, and just electric baseboard heat. It is at a rather high elevation for where I live (4500 ft above sea level) and thus gets very cold in the winter.

As baseboard heat is very expensive, I'd prefer to only heat the areas of the house that I have to when not there. The only reason to heat any of the house is to prevent the pipes from freezing.

Is there a strategy I can use to only heat rooms where pipes run through them, or should I simply resort to setting all baseboard thermostats to the lowest setting (50 degrees)? I've thought about buying a Seek Thermal imager for my iPhone and tracing the hot water pipes through the walls, but those aren't cheap, so unless I'll really be able to not heat certain rooms I'd rather not spend that $$$.

Thanks so much for any help you can provide!

Comment: Do you plan to occupy the cabin from time to time in the winter?

Comment: Yes, about every two weeks.

Comment: How frequent are power outages in the winter?  Is propane available there?

Comment: According to the previous owner, they do happen, but not that often. The owner owned it for the past 25 years, but only lived there permanently the last three. When he wasn't there before those years, he had the city shut off the water. Regarding propane, we have a 120 gallon leased tank which powers the fireplace.

Comment: Your question is framed towards a specific solution... but what about just turning off the water supply to the whole property and opening the faucets in the house?

Comment: With all due respect, if you can afford a vacation home you should be able to afford to keep the entire house at 52 to 57 degrees Fahrenheit at all times.  I did buy a 2nd home once & factored heating costs into my decision in the first place.

Comment: @freshop I do turn the water off completely (not at the street but at the water shutoff valve), but the owner indicated that the pipes could still freeze...perhaps he's wrong? Or perhaps it might be because the water isn't truly flushed out? Regardless, I'd happily do this if it works.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sure, I can afford to....but I'd rather not spend the money if I don't have to. I'm frugal, which is why I could afford the house in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably figure out where the pipes are by finding the water heater , now from there to the kitchen and bathroom by the most direct route will probably be where they are. Many times they are under the house in a crawl space less often they are in the ceiling. If they are in the crawl space I would consider self regulating heat tape , the kind made for use under a home. 
The heat tape is kind of expensive up front but if you consider the prevention of broken pipes for years with less energy use they become very reasonable.

Comment: I don't believe there's a crawl space, as it's just basement. I will check next time I'm up though. However, if I can figure out where the pipes go, is heating just that space still enough to keep them from freezing?

Comment: If in the basement heat tape would be easy if the ceiling is not enclosed. You basically run the cord along each pipe and plug it in the tape doesn’t get hot but warms enough to prevent freezing. It only uses power where it is needed like if you have a section that is warmed a bit from the sun that section won’t draw much power. Self regulating can be wrapped over itself and it won’t cause problems, cess expensive heat tapes turn the power on to the entire length when the temp gets to a pre determined level.